# Can't upload images in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to add images to my post, but I keep getting the following messege: "An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later."

Note that I can see the images in the media library.

I am working on localhost.

using wordpress 3.8.1.

Comment: I think problem may be when you upload an image, there is a chance that your comments will show in the response coming from ajax which causes error to show. I have been through the same problem and find that my comments are showing in the response.when i removed it images are uploading nicely.

Answer (score 1):

it can be due to the Plugin conflict.To check whether it is actually the case,disable all of your  plugin by navigating to **WordPress Admin Dashboard > Plugins > Select All Plugins > Bulk Action > Disable > Go**

Comment: Did you installed any media related plugins ?

Comment: I installed YARPP plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after digging into the issue, it seems like the process only fails if a post_id value is set and the user doesn’t have rights to edit the post with that id.

Go to *wp-includes/media.php*

Look for *wp_enqueue_media* function
afterwards move to this block

```
$post = null;
    if ( isset( $args['post'] ) ) {
        $post = get_post( $args['post'] );
        $settings['post'] = array(
            'id' => $post->ID,
            'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'update-post_' . $post->ID ),
        );
```

and change it to

```
$post = null;
    if ( isset( $args['post'] ) ) {
        $post = get_post( $args['post'] );

        if (is_admin()) {
            $settings['post'] = array(
                'id' => $post->ID,
                'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'update-post_' . $post->ID ),
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If you have issues in finding:

require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');” 
then find  define('WP_DEBUG', false);and add the below given code before it:

define(‘CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS’, false );
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this is a solution for my question?

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with code in my template (something related to unclosed tags), so tracing back my code solved the problem.